# What is the real name of Misha's Bidding Game?

Tags: identify-this-game

My friend went to a math camp and brought back a card game called Misha's Bidding Game that is super addicting. I can't find the real name of the game on google though, so I'm guessing it's obscure.

- Everyone gets 5 cards, and all that matters is if they are red or
  black.
- Each player arranges them in a stack face down and they go in a
  circle bidding how many red cards they can flip over from any deck
  (bids must be strictly increasing).
- Anyone can challenge a bid at any time, and the challenged player
  must flip over from the tops of anybody's stack that number of red
  cards (you can pick and choose the tops of anybody's deck, even
  flipping multiple ones off the same deck).
- If you successfully flip over the bidded number of red cards, the
  challenger loses a card, otherwise you lose a card.
- If you lose all 5 you're out.
- After a challenge, the bidding is reset.

After you've had at least one card flipped or you lose a card, you get to reshuffle your stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to [Skull](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/92415/skull). Skull has a fixed ratio of 3 red (roses) to 1 black (skull) and you only have to be correct twice to win.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the mechanics of this game are very similar, I will be sure to remember skull, although I will say I will probably prefer my friend's version. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of liar's dice, played with cards and using only the numbers ${0,1}$ instead of dice with ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$.
On Wikipedia, the article with that name gives more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately had to think of a dice game called Perudo which [according to Wikipedia goes by many names: **Dudo**, **Cacho**, **Pico**, **Perudo**, **Cachito**, **Dadinho**, **Pirate's Dice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudo) and is a variant of **[liar's dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar's_dice)**. No idea about the card game though.